# Hibernate add 'type=MyISAM' in a table creation with JPA

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, ddl

I launched my app with JPA and it suppose to create me some tables.
The problem is that Hibernate added some extra SQL code ('type=MyISAM').

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table person (id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), uuid binary(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
```

I have any idea what is 'type=MyISAM' that hibernate added to SQL queries...

Anybody here know what is it about ?

Comment: Type indicates the table engine used for the table. Innodb would be better. But more importantly, since mysql v5.1, the type keyword has been replaced by engine. Your hibernate seems pretty outdated.

Comment: I just use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependancy :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a DB dialect  problem.

if you are using mysql database then you please add below property key in your application.properties file:--

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: there was this "5" missing ^^

Answer (score 0):

... and for MySQL 8

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`